# Is there a Julia way to split a vector function without evaluting the whole vector

Tags: julia

Say, we have a function `f` which returns a vector of known size `n` with n>1.
Is it possible to access `f(x)[1]` without computing `f(x)` as a whole?

Comment: This is a technically hard problem, as you'd have to recover data dependencies from `f`'s implementation. Think of `cumsum`: `cumsum(x)[i]` depends on all `cumsum(x)[1:i-1]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not unless the vector returned by `f` is a lazy data structure—standard arrays contain already-computed values. If you want to return a lazy data structure, you can look at [`MappedArrays`](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/MappedArrays.jl). If you don't want to return a lazy data structure, then you could refactor `f` to take an index to compute, so you would call it as `f(x, 1)` instead.